# Why `OSError: [Errno 105] No buffer space available` when sending packets through socket in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, buffer, raw-sockets

I want to make a basic tool to measure the throughput of a 10g connection. To do so, I have made a client-server application through raw sockets using Python 3.

The issue is that when I launch the client, there is a point in execution that the `OSError: [Errno 105] No buffer space available` raises. I have tuned the `net.core.rmem_default`, `net.core.wmem_default`,`net.core.rmem_max` and `net.core.wmem_max` to 128 MB and the issue persist.

Does anybody have experienced the same issue? Could anybody why is this happening?

P.D.: the client code is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import struct

mtu = 1500

payload = bytearray(mtu - 14)

# creating a rawSocket for communications
# PF_SOCKET (packet interface), SOCK_RAW (Raw socket) - htons (protocol) 0x08000 = IP Protocol
with socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(0x0800)) as s:

    # deciding interface - packet sniffing and then injection
    s.bind(("eth1", socket.htons(0x0800)))

    # create a ethernet packet
    #header = struct.pack("!6s6s2s", b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff', b'\x46\xfc\x0c\x3c\x15\x27', b'\x08\x00')
    header = struct.pack("!6s6s2s", b'\xaa\xaa\xaa\xaa\xaa\xaa', b'\xbb\xbb\xbb\xbb\xbb\xbb', b'\x08\x00')
    # 6 dest address, 6 source address and 2 for ethtype = IP
    packet = header + payload
    print(f"Tamaño del paquete enviado: {len(packet)}")

    while 1:
        # inject a random string after the header
        s.send(packet)
```

P.D.: I tested this code in a Raspberry Pi 400 and it did not raised this exception (I guess because it is not powerful enough to saturate the buffers)

Comment: maybe your program sends packets faster than the network can actually send them?

Comment: Most computers are faster than the networks they're attached to, even a 10G network. But you're not paying attention to the documentation for `socket.send` which states: *Returns the number of bytes sent. Applications are responsible for checking that all data has been sent; if only some of the data was transmitted, the application needs to attempt delivery of the remaining data.* If you don't want to do that then use `socket.sendall`.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Ok, so I captured the error and used `socket.sendall` instead.  Now the client throws the `[Errno 105] No buffer space available` message, but at least it does not stop. It has been a huge improvement, thank you so much for your help.